# mapStateToProps not initialize state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using https://github.com/Microsoft/redux-dynamic-modules/tree/master/packages/todo-example
but after run show below error:

```
src/containers/root/FilterLink.js:6
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibilityFilter' of undefined

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
   active: ownProps.filter === state.root.visibilityFilter,
});
```

I'm using redux-dynamic-modules package in my projects too same error.

Comment: that error means that `state.root` is undefined, so you can't read `visibilityFilter` from it. you have to look at your reducer, not mapStateToProps to fix the issue.